# FFmpeg crossfade between two videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transition

I'm trying to take extracts from the same video and merge them with crossfade effect.

Chapters and transition are (or seem) correct. The concatenation ChapterA - Transition - ChapterB, is not fluid between Transition - ChapterB, few frames of difference. How to fix it?

The video is created using FMLE + F4VPP in 15fps.

Using Duration = 10s and TransitionTime = 5s, the resultant video is 30s instead of 25s (in VLC).

Thanks

The code as BAT file:

```
::Extract Chapters
ffmpeg -y -ss %BeginA% -i v.mp4 -t %DurationA% -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb 1.ts
ffmpeg -y -ss %BeginB% -i v.mp4 -t %DurationB% -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb 2.ts

SET /A TransitionA= %BeginA% + %DurationA%
SET /A TransitionB= %BeginB% - %TransitionTime%

::Make transition with crossfade effect
ffmpeg -y -ss %TransitionA% -i v.mp4 -map 0:v -ss %TransitionB% -i v.mp4 -map 1:v -filter_complex "blend=all_expr='A*(1-T/%TransitionTime%)+B*(T/%TransitionTime%)'" -t %TransitionTime% -c:v libx264 -b:v 3000k -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb t.ts

:: Concatenate ALL
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:1.ts|t.ts|2.ts" -c copy out.mp4
```